# Create a JSON having dynamic hash keys with jbuilder

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

Here I want to output json with dynamic **group name** rather than word **group**

```
@tickets.each do |group, v|
  json.group {
    json.array! v do |ticket|
      json.partial! 'tickets/ticket', ticket: ticket
    end}
end
```

Where @ticket is a hash like this

{a: [....], b: [.....]}

and I want output like this

```
{a: [
.....
],
b: [
....
]}
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154252/jbuilder-dynamic-keys-for-model-attributes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to @AntarrByrd there is similar answer to this problem:
[JBuilder dynamic keys for model attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154252/jbuilder-dynamic-keys-for-model-attributes)

Using above logic I have solved this issue:

```
@tickets.each do |k, v|
    json.set! k do
      json.array!(v)do |ticket|
        json.partial! 'tickets/ticket', ticket: ticket
      end
    end
  end
```